# Django: Add foreign key object to an existing object

Tags: python, django

Maybe a stupid question--

Two models `A` and `B`. `A` has a `ForeignKey` to `B`. I want to add another instance of `B` to an `A` instance.

```
a = A.objects.create(b=b1)
b2 = B.objects.create()
```

So I add `b2` to `a` like follows (so the error could be here):

```
a.b = b2
```

But that just overwrites `b1`. How can I add `b2` to `a`?

**EDIT: Here are the models.**

```
class A(models.Model):
  b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class B(models.Model):
  pass
```

Comment: Your related models, please!

Comment: @KlausD.added to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood question correctly, you want connect 'a' with several 'b'.
ForeignKey is one to many relationship,your 'a' connects with 'b', that means A can have one connection with B, but B can have several A.
Try to change relationships or use ManyToMany relationship.